# Finding missing records from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to validate my configuration. So I have a piece of code like :

```
ConfigurationAttribute.where(key: [
    'a', 'b', 'c'
  ])
```

If someone forgets to set key a, on the configuration or b, I want to be able to find the missing ones. Now I realize the record doesn't actually exists in the db, so there is nothing to find and instantiate the `ConfigurationAttribute` record from.

How would you solve a problem like this?

I can check if the count of attributes is equal to 3, that will make sure if all keys are set or not. But then again if I was troubleshooting this error, I would be frustrated because I don't know which one is missing and I would have to go and look one by one who is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `pluck` the keys from that query, and compare it to the expected set:

```
required_keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
actual_keys = ConfigurationAttribute.where(key: required_keys).pluck(:key)

if actual_keys != required_keys
  # This could be a model validation, or whatever. But for example:
  raise "Whoops! You configuration contains the keys: #{actual_keys}. Should contain: #{required_keys}"
end
```

The exact implementation details may vary slightly -- for example, maybe there can be multiple `ConfigurationAttribute`s for the same key? Maybe there *cannot* be any `ConfigurationAttribute`s for different keys? Maybe the `required_keys` varies depending on some condition (in which case, that could be a method call rather than a variable)? ...

... In which case, you may wish to modify that query, or the `if` statement, or add an additional validation, or whatever.